# Does OrientDB support data sharding and parallel query processing?

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to understand the distributed architecture of OrientDB from:

```
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Distributed-Architecture
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Distributed-Routing
https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Replication
```

Its quite clear that replication and routing are supported. But I dont understand the following:

1.Can data be sharded accross nodes of a cluster? Each node can be 'responsible' for a particular portion of the graph, but thats still not same as storing only a portion of the graph.

2.A query can be routed to the appropriate node, but is it possible to execute the query in parallel accross nodes? For instance, to process a traversal query, every node independently executes the portion of data it is responsible for and the results are later combined.

Comment: Have you found an answer for you question 2 by now? I'm REALLY interested in a graph db that would provide a way to "process a traversal query, every node independently executes the portion of data it is responsible for and the results are later combined"... and no other option besides Orient DB seems to exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regarding the first question: yes, since version 1.6. Autosharding will be implemented in OrientDB 2.0.

Sources:

- http://orientechnologies.blogspot.it/2013/09/new-orientdb-replication-engine-and.html
- https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/1522

Comment: How about the "process a traversal query, every node independently executes the portion of data it is responsible for and the results are later combined" part? This is what I'm looking for, parallel deep traversal of a sharded graph with subsequent combinations of results...